# Dataflow: Dynamic Work Rebalancing vs Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Dynamic Work Rebalancing will distribute work to workers optimally where fusion will collapse execution graph so that graph will be smaller meaning less workers are involved. How does dynamic work rebalancing help fusion such that even with the presence of fusions distribution of work is happening optimally? For example if fused worker is struggling because of let's say fanout that is happening in map step. Logically speaking more workers should be involved but graph is fused. Can dynamic work rebalancing still take an effect in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Rebalancing is supposed to work even graph is fused. Dynamic rebalancing means master asks workers to split their work and assigns those work to idle workers.

Fusion is an optimization on pipeline graph logically while Dynamic rebalancing is an optimization during runtime. You can think of that fusion is trying to reduce steps of computation while dynamic rebalancing tries to accelerate execution of each step, no matter if that step is sufficient or can be merged with other steps.

Comment: I see, so a step can contain one or more steps depending on fusion state. Dynamic work rebalance is applied at worker level, where worker may or may not be handling more than one step depending on fusion. These two concepts are independent of one another.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a FanOut step which is fused, the recommendation will be to break fusion after the FanOut. You can prevent such a fusion by adding an operation to your pipeline that forces the Cloud Dataflow service to materialize your intermediate PCollection. For example you can insert a GroupByKey and ungroup after your first ParDo. The Cloud Dataflow service never fuses ParDo operations across an aggregation.

You can find more details of this topic at the following link:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dynamic-work-rebalancing

Edit:

I believe the information in the limitation section from the dataflow docs around fusion and work rebalancing may help here. "...If a large number of steps in your job are fused, there are fewer intermediate PCollections in your job and Dynamic Work Rebalancing will be limited to the number of elements in the source materialized PCollection. " Hope that helps

Comment: I am aware of that information and you are not answering my question.

Comment: I believe the information in the limitation section from the docs around fusion and work rebalancing may help here.

"...If a large number of steps in your job are fused, there are fewer intermediate PCollections in your job and Dynamic Work Rebalancing will be limited to the number of elements in the source materialized PCollection. "

Hope that helps.